# Selenium WebDriverException Error when trying to save screenshot (Python 3.6)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to save a screenshot from a website using `Selenium` with Python 3.6 (on Windows 10). When I use the `get_screenshot_as_file()` or `get_screenshot_as_png()` functions, I always get the following exception:

> WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot get automation extension
>   from unknown error: page could not be found: chrome-extension://aapnijgdinlhnhlmodcfapnahmbfebeb/_generated_background_page.html
>
> (Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.90)
>
> (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)

For example:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
ref = 'http://google.com'
driver.get(ref)
driver.get_screenshot_as_png()
```

Is there a workaround, or another way to save the entire page as an image?

Comment: I don't know how it works for chrome but in PhantomJS you save it like this: driver.save_screenshot('name.png')

Comment: Thank you, but save_screenshot provides the same error

Comment: maybe the url is wrong ?

Comment: @Nenad no, the url is correct.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to use `save_screenshot()` method instead of `get_screenshot_as_png()` method. `save_screenshot()` method takes an argument as the name of the screenshot along with the logical/absolute path. The following code block navigates to the `URL` and saves the screenshot as `temp.png` within a sub-directory named `Screenshots` which was created within my project scope.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
ref = 'http://google.com'
driver.get(ref)
driver.save_screenshot('./Screenshots/temp.png')
driver.quit()
```

> Note that the [**`Python Documentation`**](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html) specifies that there does exists some more methods() as follows:

1. **`get_screenshot_as_png()`** : Gets the screenshot of the current window as a binary data.
2. **`get_screenshot_as_file(filename)`** : Gets the screenshot of the current window.
3. **`get_screenshot_as_base64()`** : Gets the screenshot of the current window as a base64 encoded string

---

### Reference

You can find a detailed discussion in [How to take screenshot with Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/how-to-take-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver/55120087#55120087)

Comment: Thank you, but I get the same error when using the `save_screenshot()` method.

Comment: @splinter Are you sure you are able to open up Chrome browser in general? Try upgrading ChromeDriver to version 2.30 & Selenium to version 3.5.0

Comment: this is very important! the `.` must always have `/` after!